# Oracle 11g: No more data to read from socket

Tags: java, error-handling, oracle11g

I am encountering this error:

```
java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: No more data to read from socket
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CMAREngine.unmarshalUB1(T4CMAREngine.java:1157)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:290)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:192)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:531)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:207)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForDescribe(T4CPreparedStatement.java:884)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(OracleStatement.java:1167)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1289)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3584)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3628)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1493)
```

We just upgraded our database from 10g to 11g w/o changing any connection parameters but encounters the error above.

Here are our connection url. Do I need to change anything?

```
username=test
password=test1234
url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521/testDB
driver=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
dbName=OGG
timeout=60000
poolsize=1000
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Check if is there any connection problems with your new server? Debugging can help in these situations

Comment: possible duplicate of [No more data to read from socket](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12605835/no-more-data-to-read-from-socket)

Comment: Probably not an exact duplicate, but this is a generic error message and you need to follow the steps in my answer to the linked question to provide useful information.

Comment: That is all about PL/SQL statement. I tried to fetch data as an application and it works but when deployed in our website. I am getting that kind of error. thank you

Comment: This error is a unusual because it is *not* the real error message.  There was an error on the server and the connection broke but the client does not know why.  You need to check the alert log on the database server to find the real error message.

Comment: Hey! I just restart our weblogic server :) then it worked. anyway thank you :) God bless