# SQL Error: No more data to read from socket while inserting data in table

Tags: oracle11g

I have created a table in oracle xe

```
create table tbl_unit_mst
(
  id number(10,0) constraint id_pk primary key,
  unit_code char(2) not null constraint unit_code_uk unique,
  unit_name varchar2(30) not null constraint unit_name_uk unique,
  crtd_date date default sysdate,
  is_active number(1,0) default 1 constraint is_active_ck check(is_active in (0,1)),
  crtd_by varchar2(6)
);
```

and then created a **squence**

```
create sequence seq_tbl_unit
start with 1
increment by 1
nocache
nocycle;
```

then I created a **Trigger**

```
create  trigger trig_id_increment
  before insert
    on tbl_unit_mst for each row
      begin
        select seq_tbl_unit.nextval into : new.id from dual;
    end;
```

Now when I am trying to run an **insert** statement 
    insert into tbl_unit_mst ( unit_code, unit_name) values('01','Ajbapur');
it gives an error **SQL Error: No more data to read from socket**

If I disable Trigger then it is working fine. 
can anyone help me to find out where I am making mistakes

Comment: You must be using some other program to run this? Are you using Java? Have you seen http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7839907/no-more-data-to-read-from-socket-error and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12605835/no-more-data-to-read-from-socket? What is your actual error message?

Comment: I am writing this query on oracle sql developer

Comment: In that case the second question I mention: [No more data to read from socket](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12605835/no-more-data-to-read-from-socket) is a duplicate; you need to investigate a lot further as it's probably a more serious database error.

Comment: If your actual trigger code has a space between the colon and `new.id`, you would get an error when you tried to create the trigger.  `:new.id` needs to be one, single, contiguous token.  Are you actually getting an error when you create the trigger?  Or did you just introduce the space when posting the question?

Comment: thanks @JustinCave--- I used **into:new.id** instead of **into : new.id** and it is working now

Comment: @RVB `into :new.id` would be better.