# create index in oracle db 11.2.0.4 connection gets terminated

Tags: oracle, database-indexes

I tried to create index in oracle db with the below create index

```
create INDEX index_name ON table_name (column_name) 
   INDEXTYPE IS "CTXSYS"."CONTEXT";
```

after 30 secs i am getting the below error

```
Error starting at line : 5 in command -
create INDEX index_name ON table_name (column_name) 
   INDEXTYPE IS "CTXSYS"."CONTEXT" 
Error report -
SQL Error: No more data to read from socket
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [No more data to read from socket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12605835/no-more-data-to-read-from-socket)

Comment: But i can run the same in other environment without any issue. Also if i run  the  below statement then it is able to create.                           
create INDEX index_name ON table_name (column_name) ;

Comment: @gops - that's a significantly different statement though. And you may have configuration differences, maybe patch level differences, between environments. As the answer in the linked question suggests, look at the alert log to see what actually happened. Or get your DBA to investigate if you can't do that.

Comment: @AlexPoole, i verified the logs and i can see the below errors.   
 ORA-12012: error on auto execute of job 
ORA-20000: Oracle Text error:
DRG-10502: index index_name does not exist
ORA-06512: at "CTXSYS.DRUE", line 160
ORA-06512: at "CTXSYS.CTX_DDL", line 948
ORA-06512: at line 2.   Now i gave the select grant to the table .I will try again and let you know.