# Oracle DBMS_REDEFINITION package not executing for non-partitioned table

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

I have a 30GB table named BKP_COST_EVENT and I want to partition it. I have created another table similar to BKP_COST_EVENT_PR with partition.
When I tried to run this query, it was taking too much time and the network got disconnected.
Then I again tried to run this query but getting the following error, even after 1 hr.
Can anybody help to solve this problem, so that I can partition my original table.

[image: SQL-Developer -error]

After clearing the objects, when I run this query again, I am getting

Error starting at line : 1 in command -
BEGIN DBMS_REDEFINITION.START_REDEF_TABLE('TBCAM','BKP_COST_EVENT','BKP_COST_EVENT_PR'); END;
Error report -
No more data to read from socket

Comment: Please use text instead of images. For instance the error number ORA-23539 in your question is quite telling but will not be found by other users. See [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question) for details.

Comment: sure..will edit it

Comment: @Andreas...your suggestion worked...I am not from DB background..so apologize for being naive..now it is giving this error -Error starting at line : 1 in command -
BEGIN DBMS_REDEFINITION.START_REDEF_TABLE('TBCAM','BKP_COST_EVENT','BKP_COST_EVENT_PR'); END;
Error report -
No more data to read from socket

Comment: Oh dear! BTW, you are not from a DB background and still try to redefine a 30 GB table? I know professional DBAs that would be very careful with such a task.

Comment: Can you do it offline? I.E. rename table, create new partitioned table, copy data from old to new?

Comment: Thats the poc I am working on currently..This table is just a backup table on which I am working in dev env

Answer (score 0):

If the network got disconnected, it might well be that the redefinition is still running. Please have a look at the status:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM DBA_REDEFINITION_STATUS 
 WHERE base_table_owner = 'TBCAM'
   AND base_table_name  = 'BKP_COST_EVENT';
```

Or have a look at `V$ONLINE_REDEF`.

Comment: There are 2 rows one is saying 'In Progress' and another 'Failure' . But in sql Developer it gave an error ' No more data to read from socket' ..what next should I do..keep checking  the table...?

Comment: At this point I would talk to a DBA. The "no more data to read from socket" is usually something serious. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12605835/no-more-data-to-read-from-socket) for instance.

Comment: Sure..i will have word with our DBA