# Delete with subquery, cause error No more data to read from the socket

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am creating an incremental etl procedure. on which the user can update rows. it relies on views that have fragmented data from the source, which causes a multirow problem (many rows from the view have the same key from the source). to solve this problem when a row with a given key appears in a view with last_update greater than the last etl transfer date (load_date) I remove all rows with that key from the destination table. Then in the insert these rows are newly added. The problem occurs when I try to perform a delete on my target table (I created it so nothing with entitlements).

`DELETE FROM destination_table a WHERE a.key_column IN (SELECT vw.key_column FROM source_view vw WHERE '23/08/24 13:46:58' < vw.LAST_UPDATE);`

Run this causes an error::
*No more data to read from the socket*

Comment: 1. Do not rely on *implicit* type conversion and specify [datetime literal](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/Literals.html#GUID-8F4B3F82-8821-4071-84D6-FBBA21C05AC1). 2. This error is caused by some other error, so you have to examine log files in both source and target to find a root cause. This answer has some explanations: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12614080/2778710